# spark standalone driver down socket timeout exceptions from s3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, socketexception

While running spark 1.5 in standalone mode driver encounters socket timeout exceptions from s3 and driver goes down. 
Tried playing around with network timeout values and retries. That does not help.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:649)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:522)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:401)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:326)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:277)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRestHead(RestStorageService.java:1038)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.getObjectImpl(RestStorageService.java:2250)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.getObjectDetailsImpl(RestStorageService.java:2179)
at org.jets3t.service.StorageService.getObjectDetails(StorageService.java:1120)
at org.jets3t.service.StorageService.getObjectDetails(StorageService.java:575)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:172)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:190)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:103)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.$Proxy15.retrieveMetadata(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.getFileStatus(NativeS3FileSystem.java:414)
```

Comment: Assuming that you are using your local system. check the ,latency and network connection between your local and S3.

Comment: Its not the local system. Spark is in ec2 so I assume network issues should be minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving to more number of ec2 instances or bigger machines helped. We tried along with amazon support team to figure out the issue but we couldnt reach to any conclusive results. Most probably more machines meant more partitions and smaller file size to write preventing socket timeouts